# Cannot login to some meta sites - asking a question causes a redirect loop

Tags: bug, meta, login, user-accounts

On various meta sites, including Arqade Meta, I cannot login to my account.

I use a Stack Exchange Account and am trying this on Google Chrome 35 with no extensions enabled and third party cookies enabled.  I've tried it with Firefox and it worked, and I can use the iOS app.  I also tried using Chrome's Incognito mode, with the same outcome.

I have posted to the Arqade Meta site before using the iOS app, so I do have a meta profile.

I will log in to the normal Arqade account no problem, but when I go to the meta site I won't be logged in anymore, and if I click the login link the page just reloads.  If I click the "Ask Question" button I get a redirect loop error.

According to Chrome Developer Tools, the website returns a `302: Found` response for the `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl` request, and includes these cookies:

```
gaminguser=t=[redacted]&s=[redacted]; domain=.gaming.stackexchange.com; expires=Thu, 08-Jan-2015 22:49:59 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: sanity-check: clear your cookies (or use Chrome's incognito mode) & log in fresh, see if it still happens.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome's incognito mode and it still occurred.  Signed in on Arqade, wasn't signed in on meta, nothing happens when I click login.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS for accessing the site itself? That might cause problems.

Comment: @nyuszika7h When I tried going to the meta site on https, I got this certificate warning in Chrome [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WCdt5lX.png) If I click Preceed Anyways, I am logged in.  So yes, it appears to be because of HTTPS.

Comment: @ecnepsnai that is worthy of an answer, can you please add an answer explaining what happened?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today, and the comments here helped me figure out how to work around it. The exact workaround that solved it for me was:

**On the non-meta page, click "Try" or "Help" in the top-right. Click the "Meta" item in this dropdown menu.** If I access a meta SE *any other way*, then it doesn't see my account, Sign Up sends me to the non-meta site, Log In doesn't do anything at all, and Ask Question enters a redirect loop, making the meta essentially read-only.

Edit: Also, I have to redo this every few minutes =(