# Getting logged out of meta site associated with Emacs.SE

Tags: support, login, specific-site

I am a beta user over at [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/). I am able to participate on the associated [meta site](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/) from my phone running Android 2.3.6 and Firefox 32.

However, when I switch from the main site to the meta site on my main machine (running Arch Linux and Firefox 33) I am getting logged out. When I click "login" in the navigation bar the page refreshes, but I am still logged out. When I click "sign up" I get redirected to the sign up page for the *main site* (even though the navigation bar shows my reputation and badges again, indicating I am logged in).

I tried clearing the cache and deleting cookies from `emacs.stackexchange.com`, but that did not help.

Comment: Might be https issue, see the comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235282/cannot-login-to-some-meta-sites-asking-a-question-causes-a-redirect-loop).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks. I never got the certificate warning mentioned in these comments, but based on your hint that it might be an HTTPS issue, I was able to come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is an HTTPS issue. I had to disable [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) for StackExchange. After that I was able to switch to the [meta site](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/) without getting logged out.

*This is not an ideal solution*, just posting it here in case anyone else is experiencing the problem and needs a quick workaround. If there is a better solution, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Oh, so this is a [well known and common issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd say it's related, yeah. But I never got the error messages mentioned in that post. Also, I didn't have problems logging on to main sites.